# How to implement Ads In AndEngine

Tags: android, andengine

I am trying to display an advertisement using startApp in AndEngine.

like this,

```
@Override
protected void onSetContentView() 
{
    StartAppAd.init(this, "apiID", "appID");            

    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams( RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

    BannerStandard startAppBanner = new BannerStandard(this);

    relativeLayout.addView(startAppBanner, layoutParams);


    this.addContentView(relativeLayout, layoutParams1); 
}
```

but it isn't work, please help me. I almost done other setup, like adding jar and manifest file.

Comment: logcat says "nullpointerexception"

Comment: where is the null pointer exception? post the stacktrace